# Convert Short Array to String C#

Tags: c#, utf-16

Is it possible to convert `short` array to `string`, then show the text?

```
short[] a = new short[] {0x33, 0x65, 0x66, 0xE62, 0xE63};
```

There are `utf16` (thai characters) contains in the array.  How can it output and show the thai and english words?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you *have* to start with a `short` array? If you could start with a `char` array instead (each `char` is a 16-bit unsigned integer) then it would be a lot simpler...

Answer (score 10):

You can get a string from a UTF16 byte array using this method:

```
System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes)
```

However, this only accepts an byte array. So you first have to transform your shorts to bytes:

```
var bytes = a.SelectMany(x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x)).ToArray();
```

Or slightly more verbose but much more efficient code:

```
var bytes = new byte[a.Length * 2];
Buffer.BlockCopy(a, 0, bytes, 0, a.Length * 2);
```

Comment: I would have converted to a byte array using Buffer.BlockCopy

Answer (score 7):

I'm slightly ripping off everyone else's answers, but here is a cleaner way of doing the same thing:

```
short[] shorts = new short[] { 0x33, 0x65, 0x66, 0xE62, 0xE63 };
char[] chars = Array.ConvertAll(shorts, Convert.ToChar);
string result = new string(chars);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
//short[] a = new short[] {0x33, 0x65, 0x66, 0xE62, 0xE63};
char[] a = new char[] {0x33, 0x65, 0x66, 0xE62, 0xE63};
string s = new string(a);

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: This isn't converting a short[] to a string... it's _re-writing the code_ for the short[] as char[] and then converting _that_ to a string.

Comment: @Sepster: The asker wants a string, while they said they need a short[], they may not realize that char supports UTF-16.

Comment: @Guvante "Is it possible to convert short array to string" is the question.  Not disagreeing that the answer is useful... (which is why I haven't downvoted), but as it sits, it doesn't answer _the question_.

Comment: @Sepster: But it does solve Fusionmate's problem if he doesn't have a real reason to use `short`...

Comment: @Guvante I don't disagree.  _If_ he doesn't have a real reason to use `short`. :-)  Just suggesting the answer at least needed some qualification to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

You need an array of `char`. `string` has an overload that accepts one directly.

```
char[] temp = new char[a.Length];
Array.Copy(a, temp, a.Length);
return new string(temp);
```

Unfortunately this involves copying the entire array. You could theoretically avoid this by using some casting tricks and unsafe code, but it would be tricky.

Ideally as others have mentioned, you would start with a `char[]` instead of a `short[]`. For instance if you are loading from a file, you could store the numbers you find into a `char[]` after casting them.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
short[] a = new short[] { 0x33, 0x65, 0x66, 0xE62, 0xE63 };
var contobyte = a.Select(b => (byte)b).ToArray();
var res = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(contobyte);
```

Comment: UTF8 won't work because the OP said there are UTF16 characters in the array.